# How is "for_each_possible_cpu" expanded in cpufreq.c file?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I was browsing through driver/cpufreq/cpufreq.c to understand how it works. I came across this piece of code which I could not understand.

In `cpufreq_core_init` :

```
for_each_possible_cpu(cpu) {
        per_cpu(cpufreq_policy_cpu, cpu) = -1;
        init_rwsem(&per_cpu(cpu_policy_rwsem, cpu));
}
```

When I looked through the defined macro,

```
#define for_each_possible_cpu(cpu) for_each_cpu((cpu), cpu_possible_mask)

#define per_cpu(var, cpu) \
        (*SHIFT_PERCPU_PTR(&(var), per_cpu_offset(cpu)))

#define init_rwsem(sem)                                         \
do {                                                            \
        static struct lock_class_key __key;                     \
                                                                \
        __init_rwsem((sem), #sem, &__key);                      \
} while (0)
```

My questions:

1. How does `for_each_possible_cpu` expand?
2. Why are two others `#defines` are called inside?
3. Why is the `per_cpu` output equated to -1?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> 1. How does it expand:

Keep in mind anytime you ask something like that wrt the Linux kernel, the answer is never easy... so... here we go:

```
#define for_each_possible_cpu(cpu) for_each_cpu((cpu), cpu_possible_mask)
```

You can see that this macro is really just a for loop, called with an iterator as `cpu` the `for_each_cpu` is another macro which is the looping part defined as:

```
#define for_each_cpu(cpu, mask)                 \
     for ((cpu) = 0; (cpu) < 1; (cpu)++, (void)mask)
```

And the cpu_possible_mask is a pointer to a struct:

```
extern const struct cpumask *const cpu_possible_mask;
```

Which is seen here (consisting of another macro):

```
typedef struct cpumask { DECLARE_BITMAP(bits, NR_CPUS); } cpumask_t;
```

That contains another macro (`DECLARE_BITMAP`) and it has another `#define` for `NR_CPUS`, that is the number of CPUs in the system, it should be system dependent and set in the kconfig. The macro in there is really just an array and an accessor:

```
#define DECLARE_BITMAP(name,bits) \
      unsigned long name[BITS_TO_LONGS(bits)]
```

So you can see that's the array and the accessor which of course consists of another `#define`:

```
#define BITS_TO_LONGS(nr)       DIV_ROUND_UP(nr, BITS_PER_BYTE * sizeof(long))
```

...which consists of two more `#define`s:

```
#define DIV_ROUND_UP(n,d) (((n) + (d) - 1) / (d))
#define BITS_PER_BYTE 8
```

Anyway... you can see that (A) this is a mess and (B) it ends up being a `for` loop that increments number of CPUs but also issues a second iterative action via the comma operator. How exactly the second operator words itself out is system dependent. (what's the sizeof a long on your system? what's the number of cpus on your system?)

> 2.Why are two others #defines are called inside?

That's kind of answered by #1. Since it expands to a `for` loop, you need that loop to *do* something.

> 3.Why is the per_cpu output equated to -1?

The `per_cpu` macro is giving a pointer to the CPU frequency policy of each CPU in the system, that is being initialized to `-1`. I'd have to do more research to be sure, but presumably they picked that because of the define:

```
#define CPUFREQ_ETERNAL                 (-1)
```

And the `__init_rwsem` is an architecture defined way of initializing the read/write semaphore used for each CPU's policy.

I don't know if that explanation helped much, but at least maybe it helps point you in a better direction. Good luck exploring the kernel.

Comment: Thanks. It does helped me a bit in understand. I would have to explore more to understand more

Comment: Thanks for the amazing answer.  For loop condition `(cpu) < 1` inside  `for ((cpu) = 0; (cpu) < 1; (cpu)++, (void)mask)`  is still a bit confusing though.

Comment: @Mike I just went through the `for_each_cpu` macro again. There is another definition of it in `include/linux/cpumask.h`. The example you used here is for the case when CPU only have one core, which is controlled with `#if NR_CPUS == 1`.

Answer (score 6):

Mike answer's pretty much covers it, except for one tiny little interesting bit, namely the macro used for the variable `cpu_possible_mask` (as opposed to its type which Mike did explain).

So in `cpu.c`:

```
const struct cpumask *const cpu_possible_mask = to_cpumask(cpu_possible_bits);
EXPORT_SYMBOL(cpu_possible_mask);
```

The macro `to_cpumask` is defined in `cpumask.h` as follow:

```
#define to_cpumask(bitmap)                                              \
        ((struct cpumask *)(1 ? (bitmap)                                \
                             : (void *)sizeof(__check_is_bitmap(bitmap))))

static inline int __check_is_bitmap(const unsigned long *bitmap)
{
        return 1;
}
```

It looks very odd, since the function `check_is_bitmap` returns `1` all the time, and furthermore, its result isn't even used in the macro which calls it! The compiler will definitively optimize away that call in the final binary. So what could possibly go on there?

Actually, the call is not used for runtime, but to check *at compile time* that the macro parameter `bitmap` is actually of type `unsigned long *` (hence the name of the function which does only that). If `bitmap` is of the wrong type, an warning will be issued, and a compilation warning in the kernel build is *always* a serious matter.

In essence, the linux kernel guys turned a normally untyped macro into a typed macro, something that is usually done in C++ with templates. Pretty neat.

Answer (score 0):

for_each_cpu is defined in cpumask.h, and takes two arguments - an iterator, and a mask. The mask is a cpumask_t lvalue that defines the set of CPUs to iterate over. so for_each_possible_cpu() iterates over all CPUs that could possibly be present on this boot of the kernel.

Per-CPU variables are data - arrays containing one object for each processor on the system. 
per_cpu macro definition will create name, which will hold one object of the given type for each processor on the system. Variables defined in this way are actually an array of values. To get at a particular processor's value, the per_cpu() macro may be used; it works as an lvalue, so code like the following works :
per_cpu(cpufreq_policy_cpu, cpu) = -1;

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  The for loop condition `(cpu) < 1` inside `for ((cpu) = 0; (cpu) < 1; (cpu)++, (void)mask) ` is confusing though. Not sure if you have any insight over this?